# How to check if an entry is enabled for a particular site?

Tags: templating, craft3

Is there a way to find out if an entry is enabled for a particular site?

I know there's the `enabledForSite` property, but it doesn't look like it accepts any arguments. Ideally I'd like to do something like `{% if entry.enabledForSite(2) %}` or `{% if entry.enabledForSite('siteHandle') %}`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [anyStatus](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#enabledforsite) and [site query](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/entry-queries.html#site) parameters, it should work like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries()
    .site('foo')
    .enabledForSite(true)
    .all() %}
```

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherDosin - however, this would allow me get all entries that are enabled for a particular site, rather than check if a particular entry is enabled for a particular site. I suppose I could do something like `{% set count = craft.entries().id(entry.id).site('foo').enabledForSite(true).count() %}` but it's not ideal

Comment: Why is this not ideal? This would be the query. Get your specific entry, from the specific site and check if it's enabled or not. What's wrong with the query? :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the query. It's a lovely query. It just doesn't do what I need. Your query returns all entries that are enabled for the specified site. I need to check if a specific entry is enable for a specific site. The query I posted would work, but I don't love having to do a whole new query for something that should ideally be a property of the entry object I already have.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not such a parameter. `enabledForSite` accepts just `true` or `false`. I would just go with your query.

Comment: OK thanks, appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anyone else, here's a reasonably efficient complete template I needed which outputs entries and their per-site statuses:

```
{% set entriesQuery = craft.entries
    .siteId('*')
    .anyStatus()
    .limit(null)
    .orderBy('id')
%}

{% set uniqueEntries = clone(entriesQuery).unique().all()|index('id') %}

<html>
<title>Status Report</title>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    {% for entryId, entryData in entriesQuery.all()|group('id') %}

        {% set somewhereIsEnabled = false %}

        {% set entrySitesStatuses %}            
            {% for entry in entryData %}
                {% set somewhereIsEnabled = entry.status == 'live' ? true : somewhereIsEnabled %}
                <li style="{{ entry.status == 'live' ? 'background:green' : 'text-decoration: line-through' }}">
                    {{ entry.site.handle }}: {{ entry.status }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endset %}

        <tr style="{{ not somewhereIsEnabled ? 'background:red' }}">
            <td>{{ loop.index }}</td>
            <td>{{ uniqueEntries[entryId].id }}</td>
            <td>{{ uniqueEntries[entryId].title }}</td>
            <td>{{ uniqueEntries[entryId].status }}</td>
            <td><ul>{{ entrySitesStatuses }}</ul></td>
            <td>{{ uniqueEntries[entryId].type }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```